# How can I end an elevated process from within a batch file without running the batch file as administrator?

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a batch file I've been using with success to execute a few commands including moving some files and launching some executables. I cant run the batch file as administrator as it results in some processes that need to be ran un-elevated to become so.

One executable that does need to be ran as admin I now need to close.  `taskkill /im exename.exe` wont work, permission is denied unless the batch is ran as admin.

any way to make it within the batch to execute only that command as administrator?

or conversely an alternate solution would be a means to run the batch as administrator, but ignore that for all other commands except the taskkill portion.

EDIT: The commented solution below does work, however cannot be made automated without using the /savecred option.  Otherwise you'd need to enter your password each time.  I decided against going this route and simply called another batch file (elevated shortcut) to do the closing of the exe.

Comment: You should be able to use `runas` within the batch script itself, either way, this will require the user to have Administrator rights.

Comment: okay, i was just using the batch to launch another batch file purely to close the task.
do you mean something like ```runas /user:administrator "taskkill /f /im myexe.exe"``` would work?